# ionic v4 with angular custom pipe not working

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

I create a pipe in ionic -v4 beta to reverse the array, using cmd of ionic, it is not working showing parser error in a template where I m using I given example below

```
ionic g pipe pipe/reverse
```

pipe defination

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'reverse'
})
export class ReversePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return value.slice().reverse();;
  }

}
```

using in code, generated pipe

```
    <ion-card (dblclick)="delete(i)" *ngFor="let i of items | reverse">
    <div style=" height:250px;overflow: hidden;background-color: brown;">
      <img [src]="i.imageName"/> 
    </div>
    <ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-subtitle>{{i.timestamp|date:"medium"}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title>
        {{i.amt  | currency:"₹":" ₹ "}}
        </ion-card-title>
  </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <p>
        {{i.discription.data}}

      </p>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```

it showing error

```
core.js:12501 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'reverse' could not be found ("
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-card (dblclick)="delete(i)" *ngFor="l[ERROR ->]et i of items | reverse">
    <div style=" height:250px;overflow: hidden;background-color: brown;">
 "): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@48:44
Error: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'reverse' could not be found ("
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
  <ion-card (dblclick)="delete(i)" *ngFor="l[ERROR ->]et i of items | reverse">
    <div style=" height:250px;overflow: hidden;background-color: brown;">
 "): ng:///HomePageModule/HomePage.html@48:44
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:19495)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25041)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25028)
    at compiler.js:24971
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24971)
    at compiler.js:24881
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2538)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24880)
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2547)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:19495)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25041)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25028)
    at compiler.js:24971
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:24971)
    at compiler.js:24881
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2538)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:24880)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:14051)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:12501
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:12549
next @ core.js:14528
schedulerFn @ core.js:10238
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:10222
(anonymous) @ core.js:14082
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:14019
onHandleError @ core.js:14082
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:392
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:154
_loop_1 @ zone.js:677
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:686
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:602
Promise.then (async)
scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:578
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMicroTask @ zone.js:252
scheduleResolveOrReject @ zone.js:862
resolvePromise @ zone.js:808
(anonymous) @ zone.js:724
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:25
(anonymous) @ home-home-module.js:1
```

note: I added in the app.module.ts file and also added in @ngModule declaration array

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import {AddEntryPage} from "./add-entry/add-entry.page";
import { AddEntrySecondPage } from './add-entry-second/add-entry-second.page';
import { AddEntryThirdPage } from './add-entry-third/add-entry-third.page';

import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
import { TruncatePipe } from './pipe/truncate.pipe';
import { ReversePipe } from './pipe/reverse.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,AddEntryPage,AddEntrySecondPage,AddEntryThirdPage, TruncatePipe, ReversePipe],
  entryComponents: [AddEntryPage,AddEntrySecondPage,AddEntryThirdPage],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,FormsModule,IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [
    File,
    Camera,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports:[ReversePipe]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

the proper way to solve it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your app.module.ts

Comment: i declared in appmodule ts

Comment: `import { ReversePipe } from './pipe/reverse.pipe';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent,AddEntryPage,AddEntrySecondPage,AddEntryThirdPage, TruncatePipe, ReversePipe],
  entryComponents: [AddEntryPage,AddEntrySecondPage,AddEntryThirdPage],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule,FormsModule,IonicStorageModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [
    File,
    Camera,
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports:[ReversePipe]
})`

Answer (score 0):

Better would be to have shared modules and inject it wherever required. That should solve your issue.

### Explantation

The best practice would be to have shared modules which contains common directives, components, pipes, etc.

Those modules declare and export common directives, components, pipes, to make them usable by any of other modules.

### Shared Modules

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    // dep modules
  ],
  declarations: [ 
    ReversePipe
  ],
  exports: [
    ReversePipe
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

### Usages

```
// other imports
import { SharedModule } from './{SharedModule-path}';   

@NgModule({
 imports: [
   ....
   SharedModule
 ],
 declarations: [],
 exports: []
})
export class FeaturedModule1 {}
```

Comment: showing error 'SharedmoduleModule' is declared but its value is never read. [6133]
[ts] Cannot find module '../module/sharedmodule'. [2307]

Comment: what is process to create sharedmodule